# Is there a way to run the spatial query plugin from QGIS python console?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to get all contiguous polygons for every county. In QGIS I can do this manually with a Spatial Query, but for a large data set this result impractical.

Is there a way to run the spatial query plugin from QGIS python console?